# jQuery Validator -- custom method does not hide error when valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I have a custom validator checking a value against a database of acceptable values via an ajax request. I thought at first it wasn't hiding the error message because the request was being done asynchronously, so then it could perhaps fail to return true or false in time for the validator to recognize this.

I turned async off and the error message still remains shown. How can I get this to go away?

Through console logging it **does** return true, yet the error message still remains. I tried to explicitly hide the message, but the validator still assumes false and fails to submit.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("validZip", function(value, element){
    var _id = $(element).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        url: '/xpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        data: {action:"test_checkZip", zip:value},
        type:"POST",
        asyc: false,
        success: function(response){
            if (response== 0){
                return false;
            } else {
                //$("label[for="+_id+"][class=error]").hide();
                return true;
            }
        } 
    });
}, '*');
```

Comment: could you show us your html ? the selector which doesn't work is the label one ? in your example, you seem to have double quote `"` twice instead of double quote `"` *and* single quote `'`

Comment: Its commented out because its irrelevant,  it was a hack to hide the error, and it worked. However even if hiding it like that, the validator still assumes false since the return doesn't seem to register

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nicola pointed out, there's a typo in your callback. 
Apart from that it's the callback function that is returning true/false, so actually your validZip function is still returning 'undefined'.

Try this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("validZip", function(value, element){
    var _id = $(element).attr("id");
    var isValid = false;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/xpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        data: {action:"test_checkZip", zip:value},
        type:"POST",
        asyc: false,
        success: function(response){
            isValid = response!= 0;
        } 
    });
    return isValid;
}, '*');
```

Comment: Perfect -- i was originally thinking about this before i realized i should try without async on.. then i forgot this idea as i turned asyc off, and this is exactly what the issue was -- returning undefined. Thank you :) +1

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this asynchronously? For when the result is reached, to update the validator somehow like element.setValid() or something? I noticed the latency freezes the browser for a second and I don't think that's okay.

Comment: The validation process is indeed a blocking operation, so this behavior is correct. The user experience problem can be solved by displaying a courtesy message (BlockUI plugin can do the job for you) to notify the user that something's is going on...

Comment: damn I figured nonblocking is going to raise a few problems/hacking. Do you think it's possible to explicitly tell the validator that the specific element is valid? For example: if i make the ajax asynchronous, instead of returning true, to be able to call the validator, reference the element, and notify it to be valid? Thanks for helping :)

Comment: just saw the rest of your comment, I'll check it out. But in the meantime, do you know if any explicit notifications to the validator are available?

Comment: Not sure to understand, but you can do as follows: let validZip() always return true; in the ajax call set async option to true and let the ajax call do its job. Once the success/error callback is called trigger a custom event to notify that the remote validation was performed... then handle the situation.

Comment: Right, I'm furious if there's a function native to the vslidator where you can update the validity of an element explicitly.  Any recollection of one?

Answer (score 1):

Well i think you are checking against `result` shouldn't you check against `response`?

```
    success: function(response){
        if (response == false){
            return false;
        } else {
            //$("label[for="+_id+"][class=error]").hide();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That was a typo actually, it is checking against that variable and true is reached but the error doesn't hide

Comment: No -- it doesnt help, its simply just an input with an ID.. the validator takes care of adding the error messages and hiding them, all the html is is the input itself

Answer (score 1):

Could it be because you have:

```
asyc: false,
```

as opposed to:

```
async: false,
```

Answer (score 1):

You used an incorrect answer's code from your previous question, See my answer in that question to see what's wrong. Anyway you should do like this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("validZip", function(value, element){
    var _id = $(element).attr("id");
    var return_value;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/xpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        data: {action:"test_checkZip", zip:value},
        type:"POST",
        async: false,
        success: function(response){
            if (result == 0){
                return_value = false;
            } else {
                //$("label[for="+_id+"][class=error]").hide();
                return_value = true;
            }
        }
        return return_value; //HERE you have to return
    });
}, '*');
```

The problem is that you were returning you values inside a nested function, not your validator function.

Hope this helps. Cheers